# How do I regain the use of 3G on after my phone has been deactivated

Tags: iphone, cellular-data

My phone has recently been disconnected and i was wondering if there was any way to turn my 3G back on

Comment: What do you mean by disconnected? Did your contract with the telco run out?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question - you need to get service from a telecommunications provider. If your iPhone is locked to a specific provider (if it was bought on a contract, then it almost certainly is locked to that provider), then the easiest thing to do is to get a contract with the same provider.

It is sometimes possible to unlock a phone after the initial contract has run out, but you would need to talk to the mobile provider that locked the phone to its network, in order to do that. Unlocking the phone from that network would allow you to use the phone with any compatible network.

Answer (score 0):

Your Phone still has the 3G Function/Capability.

When it is disconnected/deactivated means you do not get access to any 3G service providers.

You wont be able to receive any 3G services without having a provider.

That means the 3G is all around you but your phone can not receive any since it is not recognized on the network, not because it is not capable.

Your 3G is still ON.